# Flutter StreamProvider breaks when fetching path changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state, flutter-streambuilder

I'm trying to Stream some data from Firebase as below:

```
Stream<AdUserData?>? adUserDataStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email ?? 'null')
      .collection('userData')
      .orderBy('now', descending: false)
      .limitToLast(1)
      .snapshots()
      .map((event) =>
          event.docs.map((e) => AdUse`rData.fromJson(e.data())).toList()[0]);
```

The problem is, every time the user logoff and login, the values read using:

AdUserData? adUserData = Provider.of(context, listen: true);
are not able to update and breaks the app.

I tried many different ways to overcome this challenge, by re-starting the Stream, re-start the Widget, use StreamBuilder, ... and I fell lost, I doesn't look like I'm on the right path.
Can I have some advices, please?

This is the code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import '/screens/home.dart';
import '/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../data_format.dart';

class StartStreamAdUserData extends StatefulWidget {
  const StartStreamAdUserData({super.key});

  @override
  State<StartStreamAdUserData> createState() => _StartStreamAdUserDataState();
}

class _StartStreamAdUserDataState extends State<StartStreamAdUserData> {



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscribeToStream();
  }

  StreamController<AdUserData?> streamController =
      StreamController<AdUserData?>();

  void subscribeToStream() {
    adUserDataStream?.listen((data) {
      streamController.add(data);
    }, onError: (error) {
      print('StreamController error: $error');
    }, onDone: () {
      // resubscribe();
    });
  }

  void resubscribeTOStream() {
    streamController.close();
    subscribeToStream();
  }

  Stream<AdUserData?>? adUserDataStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email ?? 'null')
      .collection('userData')
      .orderBy('now', descending: false)
      .limitToLast(1)
      .snapshots()
      .map((event) =>
          event.docs.map((e) => AdUserData.fromJson(e.data())).toList()[0]);

  void handleStreamError(dynamic error) {
    print('StreamCOntroller error: $error');
    resubscribeTOStream();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User? user = Provider.of<User?>(context, listen: true);

    return StreamBuilder<AdUserData?>(
        stream: streamController.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasError) {
            return StreamProvider<AdUserData?>.value(
                value: adUserDataStream,
                // value: adUserDataStream,
                initialData: AdUserData(
                    adNetwork: 'Defalt',
                    auctionId: 'Defalt',
                    country: 'Defalt',
                    instanceId: 'Defalt',
                    now: Timestamp.now(),
                    revenue: 0,
                    userRevenueSun: 0),
                child: (user == null) ? Login() : Home());
                //Login() : Home());
          }
          handleStreamError(snapshot);
        return StartStreamAdUserData();

        },

        );
  }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way I know is to wrap this stream into a Riverpod StreamProvider that watches *another* Riverpod StreamProvider  that's watching FirebaseAuth's authUserChanges.